# Webpack 2 exception - Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I'm using webpack 2 and wen I execute the webpack-dev-server I get in my browser

The exception: "Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined."

This exception start when I try to create vendors chunk.

my webpack.config.js file:

```
    'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');


// Webpack Config
let webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        'main': './src/main.ts',
        'vendors': './src/vendors.ts'
    },
    target: 'web', //https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/
    output: {
        publicPath: '',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./dist'], {
            verbose: true,
            dry: false
        }),


        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['vendors'],
            filename: '[name].js'
        }),


        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            {
                // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
            }
        )
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular2-router-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    }

};


// Our Webpack Defaults
let defaultConfig = {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchOptions: {aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000},
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
        }
    },

    node: {
        global: true,
        crypto: 'empty',
        __dirname: true,
        __filename: true,
        process: true,
        Buffer: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    }
};


module.exports = webpackMerge(defaultConfig, webpackConfig);
```

my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "infra-template-ng-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A infra template for Angular2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://ilgitlab/sizmek-ui-infra/infra-angular-tow-template/tree/master",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress",
    "watch": "npm run build --watch",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --colors --port 3000 --content-base src --open",
    "start": "npm run server"
  },    
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.6",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "~0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "~5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.48",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.15",
    "codelyzer": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "tslint": "^4.4.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Angular 2 Infra Template"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@ilgitlab:sizmek-ui-infra/infra-angular-tow-template.git"
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "useWebpackText": true
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "debug": false
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

my vendors.ts

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/compiler';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/forms';
```

my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Infra Template</title>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>

    <infra-app>
      Loading...
    </infra-app>

        <script async src="vendors.js"></script>
        <script async src="main.bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you import vendors.js bundle in your index.html file?

Comment: yes I have the vendors.js

 <body>

    <infra-app>
      Loading...
    </infra-app>

  <script async src="vendors.js"></script>
  <script async src="main.bundle.js"></script>

  </body>

Answer (score 10):

This error occurs during runtime when the webpackJsonp function is undefined (obviously) hehe, but what does this mean?

So there are three types of chunks in webpack:

[image: Chunks diagram]

Initial chunks are created via CommonsChunkPlugin which to improve cacheability, however they are sync loaded and rely on the webpackJsonp function that is defined in the webpack runtime (aka entry chunk).

tl;dr your scripts are being loaded out of order. If you are using html-webpack-plugin, you can use their chunkSort option in your config to remedy this. This can also often happen via obscure combinations of multiple CommonsChunkPlugin.

My best advice would be to remove CommonsChunkPlugin and just create one bundle, and then one at a time split the code needed out into separate bundles one by one, to discover where the ordering issue occurs.

Comment: Hi，I have the same problem.But the script order is write in html without async. The file order is  'manifest vendor business', and the webpackJsonp show not stable in user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Include `vendor.js` in your `index.html`

here is full html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->
  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
      It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       and includes all files in the node_modules directory -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```